# Filter on "larger than 0.01" in Django DecimalField or FloatField

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

The table model may look something like this:

```
def product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4, default=Decimal('0.0500'))
    alt_price = models.FloatField(default=0.05)
```

The query something like:

```
p = Product.objects.filter(price__lt=Decimal('0.01'))
```

or:

```
p = Product.objects.filter(alt_price__lt=0.01)
```

Unfortunately neither works for me. I have plenty of products that fit the requirement. Querying in MySQL does work fine...

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Just in case you are wondering: the p = Product.objects.filter(price__lt=Decimal('0.0100')) also doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lt` in `p = Product.objects.filter(price__lt=Decimal('0.01'))` does not mean **larger than** but less than. You should use `gt` to find objects with `price` greater than 0.01.
[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups)

Comment: ever had a 'Doh' moment?